# Search for opponent in socket.io

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to make a script in **socket.io** using express in node.js, that searches for an opponent.

Only two players can be in a room, which means when there's no free room, it should create a new.

The logic should work like this.

[image]

I tried like this.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('search room', function() {
        //io.sockets.adapter.rooms

        for (var x in io.sockets.adapter.rooms) {
            if (x !== socket.id) {
                socket.opponent = x;
                socket.join(x);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Questions:**

- As you can see my code searches for an opponent, but if it doesn't find one, he should wait for others.
- How can I check that the player is already playing, what's the best way?
- When the user joins a room, his default room doesn't get deleted.

Comment: What's the question for your first problem? You supplied code. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Check my post below.

Comment: I might make more sense if you plan on building further more complex functionality to create a `Map();` of clients using there id as a key and game data as part of a client object.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more complex systems it's not unusual to define your own client object which holds a representation of everyone who is connected and what rooms they are currently connected to. You can also use this as a way to represent your users current state inside of the server. I suggested that you use a `Map();` for this as you can set the socket.id as the key and the value has the clients object.

A simplistic approach that you could build on would be;

Client.js

```
// JavaScript source code
var client = function client(socket) {
    this.id = socket.id;
    this.state = "newly Connected";
    this.clientSocket = socket;
    this.LobbyArr = [];

    this.changeState = function (newState) {
        this.state = newState;
    }

    this.addLobby = function (lobbyId) {
        this.LobbyArr.push(lobbyId);
    }
}

module.exports = Client;
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

//loading server side modules
var Client = require('../Client.js');

//Gets all of the connected clients
var allConnectedClients = new Map();

io.on('connection', function (socket){
  var connectedUser = new Client(socket);
  allConnectedClients.set(socket.id, connectedUser);
});
```

> As you can see my code searches for an opponent, but if it doesn't find one, he should wait for others.

Building upon the example above if we set state's for the client that is connected we are able to foreach through our map and find where the user currently is using `this.state`. If an acceptable user is not found then we could choose to emit a new message to the client.

> How can I check that the player is already playing, what's the best way?

This as before would be solved by being able to check the currrent `state` of the user.

> When the user joins a room, his default room doesn't get deleted.

In socket.io everyone is put into there own default room when they are connected to the server, So it won't be deleted.